# Issue printing two strings in mips

Tags: assembly, mips

```
.data

    string1: .byte 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' '
    string2: .byte 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!'

.text
.globl main

main:

la $a0, string1

jal PRINT_STRING

la $a0, string2

jal PRINT_STRING

j EXIT

PRINT_STRING:

addi $sp, $sp, -4

li $v0, 4
syscall

addi $sp, $sp, 4
jr $ra

EXIT:

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

I'm trying to print string1 and string2 one after another, my output should be "Hello world!" however my output ends up being "Hello world!world!". Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with my code?

Comment: 1. Start with some text, not code. 2. Format the code, e.g. use <pre> tags 3. did you forget null termination?

Answer (score 0):

Null terminate your string: replace space in `string1` with `\0`